# Unsual Gmail Java messaging exception

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-mail

I am using Java Mail Api to send mail , it works perfectly on my computer system. But it does not work on the Clients Network.. I get Java Messaging exception cannot connect to

Here is A snipet of the code

```
private static void sendmail(String file) throws IOException
{
        try {
            final String username ="username";
            final String password= "password";

            Properties props= new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

            Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                        }
                    });

          Message message= new MimeMessage(session);
          String To= "a@client.com";
          String subject= "ERROR LOG IN EXCEL";
          String body= "Testing Attached within";
          message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
          message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(To));
          message.setSubject(subject);
          message.setText(body);
          MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
          Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
          DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
          messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
          messageBodyPart.setFileName("eror log.xls");
          multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
          message.setContent(multipart);

          Transport.send(message);
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "message sent");      

    }
```

I get the Error Java messaging exception cannot mail.smtp. host smtp.gmail.com port: 465

This works however on my own system. and the email was sent successful.

Could this be a security configuration issue with the clients Network System

Comment: You need to copy the full exception with the stack trace for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: Client firewall could be blocking outbound connections. See [How to Use Telnet to Test SMTP Communication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995718%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx) for how to test if a firwall is blocking ...

Comment: See also these [JavaMail connection debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SendEmail
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {    
      // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
      String to = "abcd@gmail.com";

      // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
      String from = "web@gmail.com";

      // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
      String host = "localhost";

      // Get system properties
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();

      // Setup mail server
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

      // Get the default Session object.
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try{
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                  new InternetAddress(to));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText("This is actual message");

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```